# Its my first python project and i have been trying to move a simple rectangle down the screen as tetris blocks fall down but failing

Tags: python, pygame, tetris

I have tried many other methods, including creating a rectangle and iterating the y coordinate but that creates a long line which i do not want. This is my OOB approach to it, which is not great, but please bear with me as i am a beginner. I have also tried out the code in the documentation and it also created a line of rectangles. Kindly help me

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect=pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),pygame.Rect(x,y,50,50))
    def draw_shape(self,x,y):
        self.rect=pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),pygame.Rect(x,y,50,50))
        pygame.display.update()
    def move_shape(self,x):
        for i in range(0,10):
            x=x+50*i
            self.draw_shape(x, 0)

recT= Rectangle(0,0)
recT.draw_shape(0,0)
while running==True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    recT.move_shape(0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

strong text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the screen so the old rectangles are still there.

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

will fill it with black.  Also take update out of draw shape.  You should have one update method to update everything and one draw method to draw everything.